# Unhandled exception at 0x76b1dd74. Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, exception, com, mfc, dialog

Im attempting to read information across a serial port connection. I'm trying to send a character or string using HyperTerminal to my program. The code builds fine and will debug until it gets to the ReadFile function I'm using. Once that function is initiated it waits for the information to be sent. Once I type 4 characters I receive the unhandled Exception that i stated in the title. The break point leaves me at AfxWinMain along with hPrevInstance CXX0030 expression cannot be evaluated. I am able to send data to hyperterminal using my program but for whatever reason it crashes with readfile.

**Where Function is called**

```
void CThermotronDlg::OnBnClickedDelete()
{
Serial Port;
CString Temp("34");
bool ans;
int nItem = MyListEx.GetSelectionMark();



ans = Port.ReadPort(Temp);

}
```

**Function**

```
bool Serial::ReadPort(CString buf){

OpenPort();
LPCTSTR dope;


LPDWORD bytesRead =0;
char b[4];
BOOL ret = ReadFile(sSerial,b,4,bytesRead,NULL) ;


dope = reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>(b);
AfxMessageBox(dope,0,0);
return true;


}
```

Comment: Show us the part of your code where you open a file. Do you check if it's opened correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DWORD bytesRead;
char b[4];
BOOL ret = ReadFile(sSerial,b,4,&bytesRead,NULL) ;
```

The 4-th parameter must be valid pointer which receives actual number of bytes read. It cannot be NULL. More exactly: this parameter can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL.

Comment: Thanks that totally worked. I do have one other question, now the buffer 'b' isn't being converted into a readable LPCTSTR like I would like. Is there something wrong with my reinterpret cast? Because I'm getting Chinese symbols.

Comment: LPCTSTR is a pointer to a null terminated string. You buffer b contains up to 4 characters without the terminating null character, the length is determined by bytesRead. When working with the read bytes you should take bytesRead into account. If you only want a quick hack for debugging, then make b one char bigger, still ReadFile(,,4,,) and then b[bytesRead]='\0'. After that b is a null terminated string and you can cast to LPCTSTR.