# Windows C++ API: How do I read an entire binary file into a buffer?

Tags: c++, windows, file, input, buffer

- **OS: Windows 10**
- **Target Platform: x86**

I'm trying to load the entire contents of an arbitrary-length binary file into a character array. The contents of this array will later be copied into a memory location reserved with `VirtualAlloc`. Here is my code so far:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE payload;
    if (argc != 2) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Usage: runp.exe [payload_file]\nExecutes the specified binary payload.\n"));
        return 0;
    }
    _tprintf(TEXT("[*] Loading binary payload: %s\n"), argv[1]);
    payload = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    if (payload == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("[!] Could not open payload: %s\n"), argv[1]);
    }
    else {
        DWORD size = GetFileSize(payload, NULL);
        _tprintf(TEXT("[*] Payload found: %d bytes.\n"), size);

        // TROUBLE STARTS HERE
        LPDWORD bytes_read = 0;
        char* buffer = new char[size + 1];
        if (FALSE == ReadFile(payload, buffer, size, bytes_read, NULL)) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("[!] Could not read payload!\n"));
        }
        else {
            _tprintf(TEXT("[*] Payload read!\n"));
        }
        delete[] buffer;
        // TROUBLE ENDS HERE

    }
    CloseHandle(payload);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's an example of how it fails:

```
PS C:\path\to\binary> echo "Demonstration file." > demo.file
PS C:\path\to\binary> .\runp.exe .\demo.file
[*] Loading binary payload: .\demo.file
[*] Payload found: 44 bytes.
[!] Could not read payload!
```

The program correctly detects and identifies the size of the binary file, yet I am unable to read the contents of the file into my custom-sized buffer.

C++ on Windows is not my native language. Python is more my speed, but I don't have a choice here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you **must** read in an entire binary file into memory I highly recommend you research "c++ memory mapped files windows".  Your process may not have enough memory allocated to it to read a binary file, in its entirety, into memory.  Most programs through the ages have only read blocks into memory (yes, including the days of tape reels).

Comment: On most platforms, there is more file space than there is RAM.  You'll need to figure out how to read a file into memory that is larger than the RAM in your system.

Comment: The problem is probably `LPDWORD bytes_read = 0;`, instead of `LPDWORD` you should use `DWORD` and pass the parameter as `&bytes_read`.

Comment: If you specify `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` when you open the file it means you plan to read it asynchronously. That means the last parameter to `ReadFile` cannot be NULL. Async reads return FALSE even when they succeed too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile Long story short, remove `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews with virtual memory running out of RAM is rarely a problem.  But I think your suggestion to use memory mapping is a good one.

Comment: After you apply Mark's fix (which is the root cause of your bug), don't forget to properly null terminate your buffer before executing that print statement. You correctly allocated a `+1` byte, but you don't actually set it.  After ReadFile successfully returns, invoke: `buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';`

Comment: @MarkRansom:  Isn't virtual memory against the objective of loading an entire file into memory?  If virtual memory is in use, might as well read the file in blocks or use memory mapped file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it depends on your objective.  If it's efficiency, then virtual memory will kill you.  If it's just ease of indexing and the speed hit doesn't matter, then whatever.  But I do agree with you overall.

Comment: My binary file will never be more than a few megabytes in size. I’m looking at malware payloads passed in fileless PowerShell attacks; they’re rarely bigger than a MB.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has commented so far! I’ve been taking code samples from the Windows API documentation, which is murky and confusing. Your comments help!!

Comment: Also, unless you plan on supporting Windows 98, stop using TCHAR macros and T functions like `_tprintf`. They have been completely irrelevant since Windows XP.  It's unfortunate that the Visual Studio project templates still have this junk in them.

Comment: The Microsoft API documentation uses all that T-crap. I’m never sure what parts of their code can be abandoned and what is necessary. Thanks!

Comment: The API documentation doesn't use *"all that T-crap"*. Microsoft is not responsible for *your* education. They provide all the information online, at no cost, that put you in a position to make a judicious decision on what it means and whether you need it. Reading and comprehending that information is generally more effort than pointing fingers.

Comment: You’re right—it’s up to me to learn and use the language in the most effective way possible. Unfortunately, there aren’t many free resources for learning the Windows API, besides the incredibly dense Microsoft reference documentation. Which is why I said: “I’m never sure which parts are necessary and which can be abandoned.” That’s an admission of lack of experience. But the API documentation absolutely _does_ use the T-functions, or I wouldn’t have been using them in my code.

Comment: Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-a-view-within-a-file

Comment: That's not documentation, it's supporting sample code. Regardless, reference documentation isn't meant to be learning material. You'll still find helpful articles in Microsoft's documentation, like [Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings) or [Unicode in the Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled exception at 0x76b1dd74. Access violation writing location 0x00000000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753939/unhandled-exception-at-0x76b1dd74-access-violation-writing-location-0x00000000)

Answer (score 0):

With everyone's help, I was able to overcome the issues I was having with my code. I wasn't able to entirely remove all the `TCHAR` stuff per [selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104458/selbie)'s suggestion, as the `CreateFile` function wouldn't accept a character array for the filename, nor compile without using a `_tmain` format for the main function. (Again, C++ on Windows isn't my native language, so doubtless there's a better way to achieve this.) But I did add the `\0` (null byte) to terminate the buffer contents. I also incorporated changes suggested by [Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja) and [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom). Here's the code after these changes were applied:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE payload;
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: runp.exe [payload_file]\nExecutes the specified binary payload.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("[*] Loading binary payload: %ws\n", argv[1]);
    payload = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (payload == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("[!] Could not open payload: %ws\n", argv[1]);
    }
    else {
        DWORD size = GetFileSize(payload, NULL);
        DWORD bytes_read = 0;
        char* buffer = new char[size + 1];
        if (FALSE == ReadFile(payload, buffer, size, &bytes_read, NULL)) {
            printf("[!] Could not read payload!\n");
        }
        else {
            buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
            printf("[*] %d bytes read.\n[*] File contents:\n\n%s\n", bytes_read, buffer);
        }
        delete[] buffer;
    }
    CloseHandle(payload);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a demonstration of the program in action:

```
C:\path\to\binary>echo Demonstration! > test.txt

C:\path\to\binary>type test.txt
Demonstration!

C:\path\to\binary>runp.exe test.txt
[*] Loading binary payload: test.txt
[*] 17 bytes read.
[*] File contents:

Demonstration!
```

Thanks again to everyone for your helpful suggestions!